# How can I implement Vue 3's built in KeepAlive component to cache a child component of a page so that it only calls it's API on first page load

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

My project is Vue 3, Vue Router 4, and I'm using script-setup.

I have a reporting page specified like this in my routes.js:

```
   {
      path: '/reporting',
      name: 'reporting',
      component: () => import('../views/reporting/Reporting.vue')
    },
```

On that Reporting.vue, there are many child component NamedModule.vue's. Each of these modules call an api to pull their relevant data. All of the modules link to their own details page. The user can then come back to the Reporting page after viewing the details for a specific module.

However these api calls run fairly long, so I want all of the NamedModules to only call their api when the Reporting page is first loaded, not every time I goes to a details page and then back to the Reporting.vue page.

I'm trying to implement this using Vue's built in KeepAlive component. However I've discovered that it doesn't work when directly applied to the component on Reporting.vue like this:

```
<keep-alive>
    <NamedModule/>
 </keep-alive>
```

It does sort of work in that the onActivated fires when it's navigated to- but it doesn't cache and the component still mounts every time a user goes back to Reporting.vue from a details page.

So instead I tried to use the keep-alive on the router-view, and then directly include the NamedModule component I want to cache, like so (I'm using script setup so specified the file name -ex: CarModule.vue- of the component):

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">    
    <keep-alive include="CarModule">   
       <component :is="Component" />     
    </keep-alive>   
</router-view>
```

However, this does not appear to have any effect, and now the component no longer detects the onActivated event.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix/properly implement KeepAlive to cache a specific component?

Answer (score -1):

maybe use Dynamic components

```
<keep-alive>
  <component :is="view"></component>
</keep-alive>
```